# Depth-first search algorithm to String

Tags: java, string

studying the depth-first search algorithm, I came across a problem that I don't know how to write this algorithm to work with String.
Can anyone help me? I have no problem writing DFS for numbers.

```
    private final int V;
    private final List<List<Integer>> adj;
 
    public Graph(int V)
    {
        this.V = V;
        adj = new ArrayList<>(V);
         
        for (int i = 0; i < V; i++)
            adj.add(new LinkedList<>());
    }
     
  
    private boolean isCyclicUtil(int i, boolean[] visited,
                                      boolean[] recStack)
    {
         
        
        if (recStack[i])
            return true;
 
        if (visited[i])
            return false;
             
        visited[i] = true;
 
        recStack[i] = true;
        List<Integer> children = adj.get(i);
         
        for (Integer c: children)
            if (isCyclicUtil(c, visited, recStack))
                return true;
                 
        recStack[i] = false;
 
        return false;
    }
 
    private void addEdge(int source, int dest) {
        adj.get(source).add(dest);
    }
 

    private boolean isCyclic()
    {
         
        
        boolean[] visited = new boolean[V];
        boolean[] recStack = new boolean[V];
         
         
       
        for (int i = 0; i < V; i++)
            if (isCyclicUtil(i, visited, recStack))
                return true;
 
        return false;
    }
```

We received this code to study and write our own algorithm for String, but the problem is that I do not understand where to start and how to rewrite the code.

I have test case:

First:

```
Input:{"AA", "AB"}, {"AB", "AA"}
Text: "Should fail with direct internal dependency"
Expected :false
```

Second:

```
Input: {"AA", "AB"}, {"AB", "AC"}, {"AC", "AB"}
Text: Should fail with inderect dependencies
Expected :false
```

Comment: Please mention proper information around your question. What is the problem at hand, any code that you have written and where exactly you are stuck

Comment: @arjunkhera add

Comment: @Pshemo I know how compare String, but thx for the help

Comment: I solved the problem, assigned the desired number to the dependencies in the loop and everything works